# How to setup SSH keys on local computer terminal using Windows when my server is Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, server

So I am in the process of setting up my own server for the first time using Vultr and I'm following a guide from DigitalOcean.  The server is on Ubuntu but I am using Windows 10.  I've been doing everything through the console that's logged into my server but now I'm trying to generate SSH keys locally and I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I'm pretty new to this and I don't know if this is easily done through Windows 10.  The tutorial states..

```
Generate a Key Pair

If you do not already have an SSH key pair, which consists
of a public and private key, you need to generate one.
If you already have a key that you want to use, 
skip to the Copy the Public Key step.

To generate a new key pair, enter the following command at the
terminal of your local machine (ie. your computer):

local$ ssh-keygen

Assuming your local user is called "localuser", 
you will see output that looks like the following:

ssh-keygen output
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa):"
```

I can do all this on the terminal I use that's logged in to my server but I can't figure out how to do this locally on my computer.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and get the openssh command-line utilities via its installer.  That might be more involvement than you want with Windows.

The easier way would be to install [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), use the *puttygen* utility to create a PuTTY private key.  You can export the public key in openssh format, and use it on your server.  (puttygen does the same function as ssh-keygen, using a GUI - but PuTTY's key format is different...)

DigitalOcean has a page on that: [How To Create SSH Keys with PuTTY to Connect to a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ssh-keys-with-putty-to-connect-to-a-vps)

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this out.